# Only show Previous & Next button in Pagination

Tags: pagination

I'm trying to alter the pagination of WP so that it shows ONLY a Previous and/or Next button, and NOT the pages in between.

Using this snippet from the Codex:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
'format' => '?paged=%#%',
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
```

And these parameters:

```
<?php $args = array(
'base'         => '%_%',
'format'       => '?page=%#%',
'total'        => 1,
'current'      => 0,
'show_all'     => False,
'end_size'     => 1,
'mid_size'     => 2,
'prev_next'    => True,
'prev_text'    => __('« Previous'),
'next_text'    => __('Next »'),
'type'         => 'plain',
'add_args'     => False,
'add_fragment' => ''
); ?>
```

But I can't get it right! It always shows: `1 2 next or previous 1 2`
And I'm trying to get this: `next previous`

Can this be done by altering the parameters?

Comment: If you only want next & previous, don't use `paginate_links`! What's the context? A post loop? A gallery? Is this in the front-end or admin?

Comment: The page shows my posts, well, 10 of them. So, yeah, it's the post loop. But i want to give the option to see the rest of them. That's why i want the previous and/or next button.

Comment: Hmm, setting `end_size` => 0, and `mid_size` => 0 should solve it, if I understand you correctly (you use `$args` var as `paginate_links` function argument?).

Comment: when i set the end_size and mid_size to 0, it still outputs 1 2 next or previous 1 2

Comment: What's wrong with `next_posts_link()` & `previous_posts_link()`?

Comment: Oww, heej, TheDeadMedic, seems that's exactly what i'm looking for! I thought it applied to single posts only, not for a page containing the first 10 of them! Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to use pagination on your site, don't use paginate links function. The right way to achieve this is to use next_posts_link() and previous_posts_link() functions. These output just the link to next/prev posts like you wished.

Check these:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link

```
next_posts_link( 'Older posts' );
previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' );
```